# environmental configurations

Tags: .net, asp.net

What's the best way to modify web.configs (and other XML based configurations)?  I'm needing to automatically apply certain settings based off environment.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking dynamic modification?

Comment: Yes, i mean dynamic modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean programatically, there are classes that allow you to do so, such as [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) and [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I usually store my environmental configurations in their own folder with individual config files and reference this with the file attribute of the appsettings tag in the main web.config

```
  /config/dev.config 
          systest.config
          uat.config
          prod.config

  <appsettings file="config/dev.config">
```

This means we can deploy all our configs and just switch one value to change environments. The only draw back is this breaks some config editors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your build scripts as well.  Both Nant and MSBuild have a notion of Xml Peek and Poke.

Generally I'm against the idea of programattically editing the web.config (it will cause your site to reload).